# Why does the litteral loop outputs extra commas?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out template litterals in js but don't really get the syntax. This loop outputs extra commas between every itteration:

```
character = () => {
    const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
    return `${traits.map(() => '')}`
};
```

Full code:

```
            character = () => {
                const dice = rndAssign(6, 16),
                traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
            return `<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>D6</td><td>Mod</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        ${traits.map(elm => trait(elm))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>`
            };
```

Comment: How many commas do you expect and how many do you get?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your map replaces every element with an empty string. Is that intentional?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with loops or template literals, you are just stringifying the array that `map` returns

Answer (score 1):

Because that is default `toString` behaviour on arrays. You could use `join` on the array to create a string without commas.

```js
const table = () => {
  const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet", "Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
  return `
    <table>
      <thead><tr><th>Foo</th></tr></thead>
      <tbody>${traits.map((e) => `<tr><td>${e}</td></tr>`).join(' ')}</tbody>
    </table>
    `
};

document.body.innerHTML = table()
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Check my answer please, a `map` is not necessary.

Comment: @marekful Maybe op wants do to something for each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know what are you trying to do exactly. Why loops and why do you use literals if you can stringify the array using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and get a string.

```js
character = () => {
    const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
    console.log(traits.join(' '))
};

character();
```

Answer (score 1):

in map function just returning the empty string, so that empty array printing commas. if you return there value then it will print values.

character = () => {
        const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
        return `${traits.map(() => '')}`
    };

```
() => {
    const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
    return `${traits.map(() => '')}`
}


character()
",,,,,"


character = () => {
    const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
    return `${traits.map((v) => v)}`
};


() => {
    const traits = ["Kunskap", "Rörlighet","Styrka", "Utstrålning", "Uppfattningsförmåga", "Magisk kraft"];
    return `${traits.map((v) => v)}`
}


character()


"Kunskap,Rörlighet,Styrka,Utstrålning,Uppfattningsförmåga,Magisk kraft"
```